# using finite difference to estimate high dimensional gradient in gradient descent methods

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, high-dimensional

I'm not very familiar with optimization problem, but I know that if the gradient of function is hard to find, it can use finite difference method to estimate it. Like scipy.minimize, it would use this method to estimate gradient if the gradient is not given by user.

In my problem, the gradient of the function can be gotten easily, but it is hard to compute the gradient value. That is, we know the gradient $g(\mathbf{x}) = \nabla f$, but compute the gradient value $g(\mathbf{x_0}) = \nabla f |_{x_{0}}$ would cost much time.

So I was wondering why it is still need to calculate the gradient instead of using finite difference to estimate it. One feature of my problem is, the dimension of $\mathbf{x}$ is very large (e.g. $\mathbf{x} \in R^N$, where $N=10^6$ ~ $10^8$).

So the main problem is: **is there any defect of using finite difference to estimate the gradient of function in the high dimension problem?**

Comment: this is a bit confusing. Normally if you have an expression for the gradient it is faster to do this than to calculate each finite difference, eg there are common terms, such as with neural networks and so called "backpropagation". If your dimension is very large, you should search specifically for optimisation in high dimension.

Comment: Because my expression for the gradient is special. If I want to find the derivative value, I need to do a lot of function evaluation and matrix multiplication first. so I was wondering if just use finite-difference would be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there are two main issues with finite differences:

1. They can be expensive: it can require a lot of extra function evaluations. Technical detail: knowing the sparsity pattern can help.
2. They are a bit inexact. You loose roughly half your precision. Many algorithms require exact gradients to work properly.

So the rule of thumb is: whenever you can provide gradients, you should do so. If this is not possible then finite differencing is a good fallback method. It may be better to use a proper Derivative Free Optimization (DFO) method.

For many gradient descent applications (such as neural networks) we know the analytical form of the gradients. Clever implementations can further speed up gradient calculations.

Comment: Thx for your answer! About the second issue, if the dimension is very large,  would it 
 more easily to lose the precision?

Comment: As there are more gradients to evaluate, the probability some of them cause problems is higher.

Comment: Note that with something like Neural Networks, you can do partial finite differences: use finite differences to compute the derivatives of the final loss function then propagate this derivative through using standard chain rule updates. This can spare you the need to compute the loss function based derivatives, yet not increase the computational complexity of the derivative computation.